# Filling a MS Word Dropdown box with data from SQL DB with VB

Tags: vba, drop-down-menu, ms-word, controls

I have a DB that has answers from a questionnaire. I have a word template similar to the questionnaire that has text boxes, drop down boxes, and checkboxes. So for I can read the database and assign data from the db to the templates text inputs. I am having trouble finding a way to access the active X dropdown boxes, and to assign the right answer to them from the DB. So for example I have a drop down and the possible answers are 'yes', 'no', and 'select'. If the person did not answer then it should say 'select' on the template. If they did then the answer is read from the db and the template should should reflect yes/no in the drop down. How do I go about doing this with VB? accessing the db is not a problem, just accessing and changing what the control displays.

My code to access and set the text input boxes on the template:

```
Dim ilsh As InlineShape
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ob As Object
Dim count As Integer
count = 0


For Each ilsh In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    If ilsh.Type = wdInlineShapeOLEControlObject Then
        Set ob = ilsh.OLEFormat.Object
         ob.value = rsText(ob.Name)
         'Debug.Print ob.Name, ob.value
         ActiveDocument.FormFields(ob.Name).Result = ob.value
    End If
Next ilsh
```

This only seems to work with text boxes. What do I need to change to accomplish the same thing for drop downs??

This is how the drop down is set up:

[image: Drop down]